# ¿Estaría bien aprovechar la resolución de un problema para «intentar» fidelizar usuarios recientes?

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

Como ya sabemos, en esta red muchos usuarios nuevos sólo entran para resolver problemas concretos y una vez resueltos no vuelven más por aquí, o vuelven muy poco.

Sin embargo, hoy mismo en un caso particular se me ocurrió colocar un comentario para *intentar fidelizar*  al usuario. O sea, un comentario motivándolo a no dejar de volver por aquí, una vez su problema ha sido resuelto de forma satisfactoria.

El suceso ocurrió [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142647/29967), donde yo puse el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142639/error-notice-undefined-offset-0-al-obtener-datos-pdo-php/142647?noredirect=1#comment267067_142647) siguiente:

> Perfecto `N.`, me alegro de que tu problema se haya resuelto. Saludos
>   y bienvenido a nuestra comunidad, uno de los mejores sitios para
>   aprender a programar y para recibir ayuda. Espero que no dejes de
>   pasar por aquí para recibir ayuda o para ayudar, cuando sea el
>   momento. Saludos.

**¿Está bien hacer esto?  ¿Es una práctica que recomiendan repetir, según el caso? ¿Alguna otra sugerencia en ese sentido para ganar usuarios más asiduos?**

Comment: No lo sé... Podríamos preguntarle a los usuarios que participan activamente qué los motivo a volver/participar/responder (supongo que en chat o en una publicación en Meta)... Aunque el usuario de tu ejemplo ya viene participando hace un buen tiempo

Comment: Me parece una propuesta interesante. Quizás optaría por un mensaje que incite más a la acción (p.e. añadiendo un enlace a una pregunta con etiquetas similares y sin respuestas)... aunque requeriría más trabajo por nuestra parte.

Comment: También sería bueno no tratar con dureza a los nuevos. En ocasiones he visto que se les penaliza por falta de concreción y eso puede resultar frustrante, a la vez que no dice nada bueno de la comunidad. Pero, ¿cómo evitar esos comportamientos?

Answer (score 3):

Me parece excelente lo que propones!, pero además que fomentar fidelidad creo que también se podría **aprovechar para brindar algunos "tips" a nuevos usuarios para que mejoren sus publicaciones**, esto para que no se frustren teniendo publicaciones que no son bien recibidas por la comunidad o no cumplen con la calidad requerida en el sitio.

En este caso en particular posteriormente realizo algunas publicaciones que desgraciadamente no fueron bien recibidas por la comunidad, por el formato y la información que fue insuficiente.

Por eso la importancia de guiar también a realizar buenas publicaciones tanto de preguntas como de respuestas.

**Considero que el obtener la ayuda o información requerida, además de obtener reputación por aportar conocimiento y ayudar a otros usuarios es lo que principalmente provoca que los usuarios regresen al sitio.**